# String Equal problems in C#

Tags: c#, string, reference, equals

here is C# code.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char [] arry = {'a', 'b', 'c'};

            String str1 = 'a' + "bc";
            String str2 = "bcd";
            String str3 = new String(arry);

            if (str1 == str2)
                Console.WriteLine("str1 == str2");
            if (str1 == str3)
                Console.WriteLine("str1 == str3");
            if (String.Equals(str1, str3))
                Console.WriteLine("String.Equals(str1, str3)");

            String str4 = GetStr();
            if (str1 == str4)
                Console.WriteLine("str1 == str4");
            if (String.Equals(str1, str4))
                Console.WriteLine("String.Equals(str1, str4)");

            if (str3 == str4)
                Console.WriteLine("str3 == str4");
            if (String.Equals(str3, str4))
                Console.WriteLine("String.Equals(str3, str4)");
        }

        public static String GetStr()
        {
            String str = "ab" + 'c';
            return str;
        }
    }
```

And result is ..

```
 str1 == str3
 String.Equals(str1, str3)
 str1 == str4
 String.Equals(str1, str4)
 str3 == str4
 String.Equals(str3, str4)
```

Why all results say "Equal!" ??
As I knew, reference value are different each others.
So, results should have been "different!". but not.
Why?
It seems that there is no reason to use String.equal() !!

Comment: Indeed there is no reason when talking about `System.String`. But you could very easily have [looked that up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality.aspx).

Comment: If you want to compare any object by reference use Object.ReferenceEquals

Comment: wow you are right.. I understand wow..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing [`string.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkfd9eh8.aspx) with [`object.ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx).

`string.Equals` overrides [`object.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) (which has the same semantics as `ReferenceEquals`) and works by comparing the values of the strings. This is the reason that `object.Equals` is `virtual` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I know new konowledge~

Answer (score 4):

Equality for a string has been overridden to be based on its value.

The documentation for `String.Equals` states it checks the value, but that also happens to be what `==` also does due to the `string` implementation.

*Default* equality for reference types is based on the reference itself, but that can easily be overridden... so basically your assertion is flawed, as it doesn't take into account types that override default behaviour.

As [Jon has stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16836028/358221), reference equality can be forced via the `object.ReferenceEquals` static method, but as [Jason has stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16835940/358221), this may also fail if the strings have been interned.

---

According to ILSpy, `String.Equals` ends up using `==` at any rate:

```
public static bool Equals(string a, string b)
{
    return a == b || (a != null && b != null && a.Length == b.Length && string.EqualsHelper(a, b));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`==` has been overloaded for `String` to evaluate equality as values, not as references. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx):

> Although string is a reference type, the equality operators (`==` and `!=`) are defined to compare the values of `string` objects, not references.

However, what you need to be aware of is that some of the strings will be evaluated at compile-time, and the compiler will [intern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) them (that is, hold a single reference to a string with a given value). Therefore, these strings **might** be equal as references too (but that is **not** guaranteed to be the case).

Comment: They may or many not be reference-equal, but that's not the reason `==` returns true.

Answer (score 0):

- [**String.Equals Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals.aspx)

> Determines whether two String objects have the same **value**.

This means that your ouput is completely normal.

Answer (score 0):

Each string literal does not necessarily result in a new string instance. When two or more string literals that are equivalent according to the string equality operator appear in the same assembly, these string literals refer to the same string instance. For instance, the output produced by

```
class Test
{
   static void Main() {
      object a = "hello";
      object b = "hello";
      System.Console.WriteLine(a == b);
   }
}
```

is True because the two literals refer to the same string instance.

you can see this for completely:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

For comparing string you should use:

```
var1string.CompareTo(var2string) == 0
```

This is the correct way to compare strings

So change :

```
if (str1 == str2)
```

with this:

```
if (str1.CompareTo(str2) == 0)
```

And the rest too.

Comment: Why is this better than using ==?  The == operator compares the values of the string and it much more readable in the code.

Comment: When == is used on an object type, it'll resolve to System.Object.ReferenceEquals.
Its not the same to compare values and references

Comment: Not for strings.  On strings, the == operator is overloaded to call string.Equals which compares the values of the strings, not their references.  This is also specified in the docs for the string class.

Comment: a string is a reference and not a value type since they can be huge, and need to be stored on the heap. Value types are (in all implementations of the CLR as of yet) stored on the stack. Stack allocating strings would break all sorts of things: the stack is only 1MB, you'd have to box each string, incurring a copy penalty, you couldn't intern strings, and memory usage would balloon, etc...

Comment: But that's irrelevant to the == operator.  The == operator when applied to strings compares their values and not their references.  There is no reason not to use the == operator when you want to find out if two strings values are equal.

Comment: You are right, I just saw 
// The == operator overload MSIL:
.method public hidebysig specialname static bool
    op_Equality(string a, string b) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.0
    L_0001: ldarg.1
    L_0002: call bool System.String::Equals(
 string, string)
    L_0007: ret
}

// Calls into this:
public static bool Equals(string a, string b)
{
    return ((a == b) || (((a != null) &&
 (b != null)) && EqualsHelper(a, b)));
}

Anyways, Equals is faster than ==

close to 200ms faster?